# Ошибка при сохранении XML данных в БД ORACLE "Fatal error: Call to undefined function"

Tags: php, oracle

Всем привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите разобраться в чем кроется ошибка.

Смысл такой:

1. Включаем буферизацию, создаем XML с данными:

   ```
   ob_start();
   header("Content-Type: text/xml");
   header("Expires: Thu, 19 Feb 1998 13:24:18 GMT"); 
   header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT"); 
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
   header("Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0"); 
   header("Cache-Control: max-age=0"); 
   header("Pragma: no-cache"); echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"WINDOWS-1251\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
       echo "<MAIN>";
       echo "<ROWSET>";
           echo "<ROW>";
               echo "<CODE>somecode</CODE>";
               echo "<DESC>somedesc</DESC>";
               echo "<NOMINAL>somenominal</NOMINAL>";
               echo "<DATE>2012.01.01</DATE>";
               echo "<TYPE>sometype</TYPE>";
           echo "</ROW>";
       echo "</ROWSET>";
   echo "</MAIN>";`
   ```
2. Помещаем содержимое буфера в переменную `content`, очищаем буфер и отключаем буферизацию.

   ```
   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   ```
3. Подключаемся к базе, и вызываем функцию, передаем `content` для сохранения (код этот я не писал, взял из ораклового мануала, может в нем что-то не так).

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=windows-1251');
   $c=oci_connect("test_user", "test_schema", "DBtest");
   $rclob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
   $clob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);   
   $s = oci_parse($c, "begin :ret:=create_sm.get_xml_data(:data, :out); end;");    
   oci_bind_by_name($s, ":data", $clob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
   oci_bind_by_name($s, ":ret", $rclob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
   oci_bind_by_name($s, ":out", $out, 1000);
   $clob->writeTemporary($content);
   $r = oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT); // use OCI_DEFAULT so $lob->save() works
   //$e = oci_error($s);
   //var_dump($e);
   oci_commit($c);
   //echo $out;
   $returnvalues = convertDateBackwards($rclob->load());
   $returnvalues = str_replace("<SECURITY>","<SECURITY ret=\"".$out."\">",$returnvalues);
   //echo convertDateBackwards($rclob->load());
   echo $returnvalues;
   $clob->free(); // close LOB descriptor to free resources
   $rclob->free(); // close LOB descriptor to free resources
   oci_free_statement($s);
   oci_close($c);
   ```

Ошибка появляется вот такая:

```
Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 14: PLS-00201: идентификатор 'CREATE_SM.GET_XML_DATA' должен быть объявлен ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in C:\webserver\www.site.ru\www\blocks\create_xml.php on line 57

Fatal error: Call to undefined function convertDateBackwards() in C:\webserver\www.site.ru\www\blocks\create_xml.php on line 62
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ошибке ясно видно что вы пытаетесь использовать не функцию которой не существует.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас покопаюсь, проверю!

Comment: может она конечно где то и есть, но определена где то в другом файле, и не подключена к этому скрипту, смотрите :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем на счет WARNING - проблема связана была с правами доступа вызова функции GET_XML_DATA, у пользователя не хватало прав на выполнение функции.

На счет Fatal error - согласен с ответом [@gera](/users/8949/gera), забыл докопировать функцию :)